# adding cck fields to lightbox overlay?

Tags: 7, entities, javascript

I was wondering if it was possible to add cck fields of a certain node into the overlay of an image that is part of that node? The idea is to get a description of that image going in the overlay.

Comment: I think you can use a jQuery.mouseenter on the image field. so once the mouse is placed on the image you can use jQuery.load to show the description. This is the easiest way. If not you can try Colorbox module. But i am sure that it is not supported for nodes:(

Comment: This assumes that that you can enter a description for the image field to begin with. The problem that when editing the imagefield there seems to be no option for a description. From what I've gathered, this seems to be a D7 specific issue.

Comment: [This][1] question goes into it in more detail


  [1]: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/29252/get-the-title-attribute-into-a-lightbox-frame